# List up files shared with me

Tags: search, enterprise-search, content-search-web-part, onedrive-for-business, cswp

On a SharePoint 2016 on-prem based Intranet I  want to list up files that are  shared with me (the logged in user). I don't want to list up documents the user has contribute permissions on, but want to explicitly show only the document shared with the user that is logged in.

I have tried this KQL query in a content search web part, but it didn't work:

```
(SharedWithUsersOWSUSER:{User} AND contentclass:STS_ListItem_MySiteDocumentLibrary)
```

Basically I am trying to show the content found on my site > one drive, under "Shared with me", in a content search web part:

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Edit:
I managed to get the "Documents shared with me" by using this query:

```
  People:{user}(contentclass:"STS_ListItem_MySiteDocumentLibrary")
```

But this only shows the word documents, and not for instance powerpoint documents. I also noticed not all documents that get shared with me are shown in One Drive.

This is getting where confusing now. Any ideas why I can only query and get back .docx - files, and not .pptx.

Any ideas why only some files are shown in OneDrive "shared with me" ?